# Remove duplicates in xml based on attributes values and several nodes' innertext

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, filtering

I have the below input XML which needs to be transformed with an xslt

Input Xml:

```
<element>
  <childelement xml:type="base" id="645">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>A</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement >
  <childelement xml:type="level1" id="646">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>B</seg2>
    <seg3>1</seg3>
  </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level2" id="656">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>C</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
</element>
<element>
  <childelement xml:type="base" id="647">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>A</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level1" id="648">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>B</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level2" id="649">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>D</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
</element>
```

Expected output:

```
<element>
  <childelement xml:type="base" id="645">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>A</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement >
  <childelement xml:type="level1" id="646">
        <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>B</seg2>
        <seg3>1</seg3>
   </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level2" id="656">
        <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>C</seg2>
        <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
</element>
<element>
  <childelement xml:type="base" id="647">
        <seg1>a</seg1>
        <seg2>A</seg2>
        <seg3>0</seg3>
      </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level2" id="649">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>D</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
</element>
```

So what I'd like to do is identifying all the childelements which have the same attribute but base (i.e. here level1 and level2 potentially higher levels) and the same innertext for seg1 and seg2, keep only the first one with the highest seg3 (in this case the one with id = 646 and filter out the one with id = 648).

Is such a processing possible with xml / xlst (matching duplicates based on attributes and innertext)?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Can you use XLST 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="dist" match="childelement[not(@xml:type = 'base')]"
  use="concat(@xml:type, '|', seg1, '|', seg2)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childelement[not(@xml:type = 'base')][seg3 &lt; max(key('dist', concat(@xml:type, '|', seg1, '|', seg2))/seg3)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied with Saxon 9 to your input sample (with a `root` element added) the output is

```
<root>
<element>
  <childelement xml:type="base" id="645">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>A</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level1" id="646">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>B</seg2>
    <seg3>1</seg3>
  </childelement>
  <childelement xml:type="level2" id="656">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>C</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
</element>
<element>
  <childelement xml:type="base" id="647">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>A</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>

  <childelement xml:type="level2" id="649">
    <seg1>a</seg1>
    <seg2>D</seg2>
    <seg3>0</seg3>
  </childelement>
</element>
</root>
```

If you need to use an XSLT 1.0 processor then

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="dist" match="childelement[not(@xml:type = 'base')]"
  use="concat(@xml:type, '|', seg1, '|', seg2)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childelement[not(@xml:type = 'base')]">
  <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="key('dist', concat(@xml:type, '|', seg1, '|', seg2))">
    <xsl:sort select="seg3" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1 and generate-id() = generate-id($this)">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

is my version of translation the XSLT 2.0 approach into XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Thanks Martin for taking the time. I'm trying to use it with a c# console application but get the error 'max()' is an unknown XSLT function.

Comment: If you want to use XSLT 2.0 with C# you have the option of using the .NET version of Saxon 9 or XmlPrime. Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform does not support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @azazaz, I have edited the answer to provide an XSLT 1.0 solution

Comment: It looks like it works! I'll try to implement it fully tomorrow and let you know. In the meantime, thank you again for your time.

Comment: oh and another thing, do you believe the same coul be achieved with xpath only?

Answer (score -1):

And the same thing for XSLT 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="similar" 
         match="childelement[not(@xml:type = 'base')]" 
         use="concat(@xml:type, '|', seg1, '|', seg2)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="childelement[@xml:type!='base']">
    <xsl:variable name="highestId">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('similar', concat(@xml:type, '|', seg1, '|', seg2))">
            <xsl:sort select="seg3" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="@id = $highestId">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```